# Caching model properties in Django

Tags: django

In my Django app, I have a very repetitive query calling `for item in self.schemaitem_set.all()` very often. I feel this code is vastly inefficient. I am looking for a way to cash the query. Do you guys know how I could make the code below better?

```
@property
def gross(self):
    gross_sum = Decimal('0')
    for item in self.schemaitem_set.all():
        gross_sum += item.gross
    return gross_sum

@property
def net(self):
    net_sum = Decimal('0')
    for item in self.schemaitem_set.all():
        net_sum += item.net
    return net_sum

@property
def deposit(self):
    deposit_sum = Decimal('0')
    for item in self.schemaitem_set.all():
        deposit_sum += item.deposit
    return deposit_sum

@property
def service_cost(self):
    service_cost = Decimal('0')
    if self.net > Decimal('150'):
        pass
    else:
        service_cost += Decimal('9.99')
    return service_cost

@property
def service_cost_vat(self):
    service_cost_vat = Decimal('0')
    if self.net > Decimal('150'):
        pass
    else:
        service_cost_vat += Decimal(f'{9.99*0,19}')
    return service_cost_vat

@property
def vat(self):
    vat = Decimal('0')
    for item in self.schemaitem_set.all():
        vat += item.vat
    return vat
```

Comment: Really, so the database is not hit every time i call shemaitem_set.all()? So, I thought there would be 5 DB queries in the code above

Comment: No, you are correct, the DB would be hit *each time you execute* this code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The DB would still only be hit once per method right?  That is what I meant, but I realize that isn't exactly what he was asking.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  Can you show *how* you call these methods?  I don't think there is a solution using caching, but you can probably combine these methods so that they use the same queryset.

Comment: I call them in a template ... so just regular template tag.

Comment: When you use these methods in a template, do you always use all 6 of them?  If so, you can combine them into a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) for this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

@property
def gross(self):  
    return self.schemaitem_set.all().aggregate(Sum('gross'))
```

Now, the computation is done at the database level, and only the sum of the columns is queried.

If you constantly perform these methods together on the same template, you can reduce them to one query:

```
def get_aggregate_data(self):
   qs = self.schematem_set.all(
   ).aggregate(Sum('gross'), Sum('net'), Sum('deposit'), Sum('vat')) 
   qs.service_cost, qs.service_cost_vat = (Decimal('9.99'), Decimal(f'{9.99*0,19}')) if qs.net > Decimal('150') else (Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'))
   return qs
```

You can access the aggregates in your template like this:

```
{{ qs.price__gross }}
{{ qs.price__net }}
{{ qs.service_cost }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is a great suggestion. But the database will not cash anything for the other queries, right? So there is still the problem regarding the multitude of queries.

Comment: @Xen_mar I don't know enough about caching to give you an answer to that, but I trust Daniel Roseman's comment (which he removed), in saying that *you can't cache reverse relations*.

Comment: @Xen_mar I added an update with an example for this

Comment: Oh, I really like this approach!